# WHERE T1.col < T2.col … < > を数値ではなく文字列に適用した場合、!=と同じ結果を得る？

Tags: mysql

A～Zまでのアルファベットを格納しているカラムcolに対して、下記のように記述しているSQLがあるのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？

```
WHERE T1.col < T2.col
```

---

< > を数値ではなく文字列に適用する意味を教えてください。
もしかして、!= ってこと？

```
WHERE T1.col != T2.col
```

---

**対象SQL**

```
SELECT
 T1.col t1, 
 T2.col t2 
FROM
 Tbl T1, 
 Tbl T2 
WHERE
 T1.col < T2.col
```

**知りたいこと**

・「WHERE T1.col < T2.col」の意味
・「WHERE T1.col > T2.col」との違い
・「WHERE T1.col != T2.col」との違い

Answer (score 3, accepted):

文字列には辞書順と呼ばれる比較方法が適用されます。大雑把に言うと文字列`A`と`B`を比較する場合

- 先頭の文字`A[0]`と`B[0]`の大小を比較する
- `A[0]` < `B[0]`であれば`A` < `B`、`A[0]` > `B[0]`であれば`A` > `B`とする
- `A[0]` = `B[0]`の場合、次の桁`A[1]`、`B[1]`について同様の比較を行う
- 片方の文字列の末尾まで比較して差が無かった場合、`A`と`B`の長さの比較結果を使用する

というようなルールで順序が決定され、もちろん結果は`!=`とは異なります。

なお上の比較で文字同士の比較を行っていますが、その結果はデータベースの場合カラムの**照合順序**で指定されているルールによって決まります。